# Random numbers out of a set

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random, numbers

I need some random numbers out of a given set. Both the quantity of the numbers and the numbers itselves have to be chosen randomly.
Say the range for the quantity is 2 to 5 and the set of numbers is 1 to 4. Some possible results could be:
13; 334; 42331; ...

```
min <input type = "number" id = "min_txt" value="2" min="1" />
max <input type = "number" id = "max_txt" value="5" min="1" />
numbers <input type = "number" id = "numbers_txt" value="4" min="1" max="5" />

<button type="button" onClick="func()">click</button>
<input type = "text" id = "arr_txt" />

<script>
function func(){
    var min = min_txt.value;
    var max = max_txt.value;
    var numbers = numbers_txt.value;
    var arr = [];
    arr_txt.value="";

    // set quantity (e.g. 3)
    var quantity = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; 

    // actual operation
    for (var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
        var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * numbers) + 1);
        arr.push(number);
    }

    // output the result
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       arr_txt.value=arr_txt.value+arr[i];
    }
}
</script>
```

The problem is, I barely get the results I expect. Sometimes I get something like 31112342144313124134342131213224 with the parameters above.

Comment: make a filter over your arr.lenth loop upto some range length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`min` is a string. When you calculate quantity by adding `Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1))` and `min`, it performs string concatenation, not addition. So you may end up with something like "12" or "22" or "52" as a result for quantity.

You can prevent this by ensuring that your numerical values are actually numbers:

```
var min = parseInt(min_txt.value);
var max = parseInt(max_txt.value);
var numbers = parseInt(numbers_txt.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRandom(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function getRandomArray(min, max, minCount, maxCount) {
    var count = getRandom(minCount, maxCount);
    var arr = [];

    while (count-- > 0)
        arr.push(getRandom(min, max));

    return arr;
}
```

Use the above functions with the proper int parameters